# Create an array containing values oscillating between two boundaries

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am wondering if there is a way to generate an array which, for example, would start from 0, increase by 1 until it reaches 3, and then decreases by 1 until it reaches 0 again, eg

[0,1,2,3,2,1,0]

and if I could specify the number of values in the array ahead of time, that would be great. For example, if I could set the lower bound(0), upper bound (3), increment(1), and length of array (9):

[].oscillate(0,3,1,9) would give me this:

[0,1,2,3,2,1,0,1,2]

As of now, the best thing I can come up with is this:

```
values = []
  until values.count >= 9
    values.pop
    x=0
    values << x && x+=1 while x < 3
    values << x && x-=1 while x >= 0 

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def oscillate(a, b, step, num)
  ramp_up = a.step(b, step).entries
  ramp_down = ramp_up.drop(1).reverse.drop(1)
  ramp_up.concat(ramp_down).cycle.take(num)
end
```

How does this work?

- creates the `ramp_up` and `ramp_down` arrays
- concatenates the two arrays
- `cycle` returns an ever-repeating enumerator
- `take` materializes `num` elements from that enumerator. Other than suggested in a comment, this does not recalculate anything. It just materializes entries from the enumerator.

Comment: This is good but it recalculates the entire sequence for each take. OK for small sequences, but I'd recommend adding memoization if the sequence is large.

Comment: @mattf glad to hear this is helpful! If you like this answer consider accepting it with the checkmark.

Comment: @markthomas not sure I follow, what exactly to you feel is "recalculated" here? Where exactly would you add memoization?

Comment: @akuhn Sorry I misread the problem. This intended to be called exactly once. Sorry for the confusion. I will reiterate that this is a good solution!

Answer (score 3):

Fun exercise!

You're looking for a [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave).
The formulas on Wikipedia are for the standard shape (between -1 and 1), but here's an adapted version for any wave position, period and amplitude :

```
def triangle_wave(min, max, increment, length, offset = 0)
  amplitude = max - min
  period = 2 * amplitude
  Array.new(length) do |i|
    min + ((increment * (i + offset) - amplitude) % period - amplitude).abs
  end
end

puts triangle_wave(0, 3, 1, 9) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
# true

p triangle_wave(-3, 3, 1, 20)
# => [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2]

p triangle_wave(5, 9, 2, 9)
# => [5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5]

p triangle_wave(0, 1, 0.25, 9)
# => [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.0]

p triangle_wave(-3, 0, 1, 9, 3)
# => [0, -1, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2]

p triangle_wave(0, 1, 1, 9)
# => [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

`min` should be lower than `max`, `increment` should be positive and `max-min` should be divisible by `increment`. Those are restrictions on the input but not on the output : any wave can be generated.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This problem could be a textbook example of the use of Ruby's [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/).

As the question only makes sense when there is a non-negative integer `steps` such that `high = low + steps * increment`, I've replaced the method's argument `high` with `steps`.

```
def oscillate(low, steps, increment, length)
  high = low + steps * increment 
  n = low
  length.times.each_with_object([]) do |_,a|
    a << n
    n += (n==low)..(n==high-increment) ? increment : -increment
  end
end

oscillate(0,3,1,9)
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]

oscillate(-1, 4, 2, 16)    
  #=> [-1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 1, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

To show what's happening here I will modify the code a little and add some `puts` statements, then run it with the first example.

```
def oscillate(low, steps, increment, length)
  high = low + steps * increment
  puts "high = #{high}" 
  n = low
  length.times.each_with_object([]) do |_,a|
    a << n
    diff = (n==low)..(n==high-increment) ? increment : -increment
    print "n=#{n}, a<<n=#{a}, diff=#{diff}, " 
    n += diff
    puts "n+=diff=#{n}" 
  end
end

oscillate(0,3,1,9)
high = 3
n=0, a<<n=[0],                         diff= 1, n+=diff=1
n=1, a<<n=[0, 1],                      diff= 1, n+=diff=2
n=2, a<<n=[0, 1, 2],                   diff= 1, n+=diff=3
n=3, a<<n=[0, 1, 2, 3],                diff=-1, n+=diff=2
n=2, a<<n=[0, 1, 2, 3, 2],             diff=-1, n+=diff=1
n=1, a<<n=[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1],          diff=-1, n+=diff=0
n=0, a<<n=[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0],       diff= 1, n+=diff=1
n=1, a<<n=[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],    diff= 1, n+=diff=2
n=2, a<<n=[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2], diff= 1, n+=diff=3
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Nice. It's the first time I see a legitimate use of the flip-flop.